# Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:"_yylval", referenced from _yylex on Mac OS

Tags: macos, bison, flex-lexer

I'm trying out some examples from O'Reilly Flex & Bison. The first Bison and Flex program I'm trying gives me next error when linking the sources:

> Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:   "_yylval", referenced
>
> from:
>
> ```
>   _yylex in lex-0qfK1M.o
> ```

As I'm new to Mac and I'm just trying the examples, I have no clue what's wrong here.

l file:

```
/* recognize tokens for the calculator and print them out */
%{
#include "fb1-5.tab.h"
%}

%%
"+"     { return ADD; }
"-"     { return SUB; }
"*"     { return MUL; }
"/"     { return DIV; }
"|"     { return ABS; }
[0-9]+  { yylval = atoi(yytext); return NUMBER; }
\n      { return EOL; }
[ \t]   { /* Ignore whitespace */ }
.       { printf("Mystery character %c\n", *yytext); }
%%
```

y file:

```
/* simplest version of calculator */
%{
#include <stdio.h>
%}
/* declare tokens */
%token NUMBER
%token ADD SUB MUL DIV ABS
%token EOL
%%
calclist: /* nothing */ matches at beginning of input
 | calclist exp EOL { printf("= %d\n", $1); } EOL is end of an expression
 ;
exp: factor default $$ = $1
 | exp ADD factor { $$ = $1 + $3; }
 | exp SUB factor { $$ = $1 - $3; }
 ;
factor: term default $$ = $1
 | factor MUL term { $$ = $1 * $3; }
 | factor DIV term { $$ = $1 / $3; }
 ;
term: NUMBER default $$ = $1
 | ABS term { $$ = $2 >= 0? $2 : - $2; }
 ;
%%
main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    yyparse();
}

yyerror(char *s)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "error: %s\n", s);
}
```

Command line:

```
bison -d fb1-5.y
flex fb1-5.l
cc -o $@ fb1-5.tab.c lex.yy.c -ll
```

I use -ll instead of -lfl because apparently on Mac os x, the fl library isn't there.

Output:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_yylval", referenced from:
      _yylex in lex-0qfK1M.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Your .y file is a copy of your .l file -- which will cause all kinds of errors from bison.  yylval is defined in the code generated by bison...

Comment: Ow, my bad, will edit the post.

Comment: I'll try this tonight http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3298718/undefined-reference-to-yyparse-flex-bison , maybe it solves the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently the Flex & Bison book from O'Reilly is full of errors.

See http://oreilly.com/catalog/errataunconfirmed.csp?isbn=9780596155988

Very weird that they do not even bother test their own examples...

Part of the question is solved in [Undefined reference to yyparse (flex & bison)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3298718/undefined-reference-to-yyparse-flex-bison) but not everything. See the errataunconfirmed page.

Answer (score 5):

I caused a similar error by compiling a lex file that began

```
%{
#include "y.tab.h"
%}
```

using the command

```
gcc -ll lex.yy.c
```

This worked:

```
gcc -ll y.tab.c lex.yy.c
```

What's going on? There's a declaration in y.tab.h

```
extern int yylval
```

which allows lex.yy.c to compile.  However, lex.yy.o needs to be linked against an object file that includes yylval, such as y.tab.o

Comment: Thank you VERY much. This is so arcane and should be mentioned in the [Lex and Yacc](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9781565920002.do) book I'm following.